# Prediction in a BigQuery ML linear regression model

Tags: google-bigquery

To predict customers likelihood of purchasing a product BigQuery ML linear regression model is being used.

City name is used as a predictive component.  In order to train the model data must be organized as columns.

Please advise which of the following method should be used

1. one hot coding method
2. Cloud data fusion

Did not get the expected results with data fusion.

Answer (score 0):

By default BQML applies one-hot encoding to categorical features. For linear regression models, dummy encoding is also supported: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/auto-preprocessing#category_feature_encoding.